# Vue! не работает код

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

Всем привет, недавно начал изучать vue и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что редактор подчеркивает, когда я ставлю одинарные кавычки в классе

```
:class="{'is-active':tab.selected}"
```

Возможно, этот метод уже не правильный или как можно по другому эту строчку перезаписать.
Делаю по уроку и на видео работает, но у меня подчеркивает, пишу на webstorme, кто может объяснить в чем проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.css">
        <style type="text/css">body {padding-top:40px;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="root" class="container">
        <tabs>
            <tab name="About Us" v-bind:selected="true">
                <h1>HELLO</h1>
            </tab>
            <tab name="About Our coulter">
                <h1>AGE</h1>
            </tab>
            <tab name="About Usdsfsdf">
                <h1>EVAR</h1>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </div>
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="js/VueTest.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

VueTest.js:

```
        Vue.component('tabs',{
       template:'<div>' +
       '<div class="tabs">\n' +
       '  <ul>\n' +
       '<li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{'is-active':tab.selected}">' +
            '<a href="#">{{tab.name}}</a>' +
        '</li>'+
       '  </ul>\n' +
       '</div>' +
       '<div class="tabs-details"><slot></slot></div>' +
       '</div>',
        data:function () {
          return{
             tabs:[]
          } ;
        },

        created:function () {
           this.tabs=this.$children;
        }
    });

    Vue.component('tab',{
       template:'<div><slot></slot></div>',
        props:{
           name:{required:true},
           selected:{default:false}
        }
    });


    var app = new Vue({
        el:'#root'
    });
```

Comment: а что за ошибка возникает? Наведите курсор на подчеркивание - что за сообщение там? И какая у вас версия WebStorm? Что за расширение файла - `.vue` или `.html`?

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание: WebStorm поддерживает только [single-file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), компоненты, объявленные в HTML файлах (вроде того, что у Вас) не поддерживаются и поддерживаться не будут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно экранировать кавычки обратным слешем:
`'<li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{\'is-active\':tab.selected}">' +`

[экранирование специальных символов](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)